# How to truncate a table so that new values can be entered later on, but still display the previous values?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I have the following servlet called "PayslipAdmin which retrieves information from a database as shown below, but only when the "PayrollRun" servlet is run:

```
public class PayslipAdmin extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        String employee_id = ""; 

                   if(session != null) { 
                       employee_id = (String)session.getAttribute("employeeid"); 
                   }     

                   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
                   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
                   PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT run FROM payroll_system.payslip WHERE employeeID = ?); 
                   ps.setString(1, employee_id);
                   ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
                   st = rs.next(); 
                   payroll_run = rs.getBoolean("run"); 


               if(payroll_run) {    


                   try{ 
                     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
                       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
                       PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select FirstName, LastName, Address, Role, BankName,AccNumber,SuperNumber,SuperCompany from payroll_system.employee_info where employeeID = ?");
                       ps.setString(1, employee_id);

                   }catch(Exception e)
                   {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
           }
```

}

The above servlet will only run if the "PayrollRun" servlet has been executed, as shown below: 
    public class PayrollRun extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try{ 

         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 

            PreparedStatement pss = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO payroll_system.payslip(run) VALUES("1")");
            pss.executeUpdate(); 

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO payroll_system.payslip(employeeID) SELECT employeeID FROM payroll_system.employee_info");
            ps.executeUpdate(); 


            String paydate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").format(new java.util.Date());
            PreparedStatement ps0= con.prepareStatement("UPDATE payroll_system.payslip SET paydate=?");
            ps0.setString(1, paydate);
            ps0.executeUpdate(); 

            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE payroll_system.payslip pslip JOIN payroll_system.employee_info info ON pslip.employeeID = info.employeeID SET pslip.role = info.Role ");
            ps1.executeUpdate(); 






}catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

When a payroll admin presses a html button to run the payroll, the "PayrollRun" servlet is run. When an employee presses a html button to view their payslip, the "PayslipAdmin" servlet is run. But this should only happen when the payroll admin has run the "PayrollRun" servlet.

**My question**

Everytime a payroll admin activates the "PayrollRun" servlet, the boolean value "run" will be set to true. This will allow employees to view their payslips through in the "PayslipAdmin" servlet (which is also shown above, but not complete yet). When the admin runs "PayrollRun", I need to truncate a few tables so that the employee can then enter new values managed by other servlets (irrelevant to this question). However, I also need to ensure that through the "PayslipAdmin" servlet, the employees can still view their payslip, but how can I achieve this if the tables are to be truncated?

Comment: Can you consolidate these into a single servlet?

Comment: @ck1 Hi! Unfortunately that's not possible as the "PayrollRun" servlet must be executed first so that the "PayslipAdmin" can display the payslip information to the employees. Unless you can suggest a workaround, which may be possible. When a payroll admin presses a html button to run the payroll, the "PayrollRun" servlet is run. When an employee presses a html button to view their payslip, the "PayslipAdmin" servlet is run. But this should only happen when the payroll admin has run the "PayrollRun" servlet. Could it be possible to merge them and still achieve?

Comment: you can use httpclient to create a request to your another servlet when PayrollRun is executed.

Comment: @DemonColdmist Hi Demon. How could this be done? Could you please provide a basic block of code? :) Thanks

Comment: Can you use the database to save the state of the payroll actions?

Comment: @ck1 Hmm maybe that could work. But everytime the payroll admin executes "PayrollRun" servlet, I need to reset the databases. However, I think Demon's method of httpclient sounds like it might work. But I'm unsure how to perform that.

Comment: Not crazy about that idea. You should find a way to tie them together at the server end.

Comment: Agree with EJP, business logic should be in Java Beans / Service layer, not within JSPs or Servlets.

Comment: You don't need  `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()` at all, let alone twice, and you have never needed the `toInstance()` part.

Comment: @MickMnemonic That's not what I said. I'm commenting on a proposal to put database linking logic into the *client*, which is certainly not where it belongs.

Comment: @EJP, ok, but do you disagree with me?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I disagree with your claim that I said what you claimed I said. I don't care to have words put into my mouth. OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,you need download the httpclient's jars by maven or something else.[here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/quickstart.html) is the quickstart of httpclient.well, when PayrollRun has done its business, then use httpclient to create a new request to PayslipAdmin which means add some code append to PayrollRun in the "try".Sample code:

```
Request.Get("your servlet url, like http://localhost:8080/...").execute().returnContent();
```

It's just sample code, you need to change the code according to your business.As my concern, you don't need returnContent() here.

Comment: Thanks Demon. This is not an actual system by the way, just a mock. Can I just type the servlet name instead of the url?

Comment: No, it would't work if you type the servlet name.Actually, you don't need to write two servlet because it is a mock.Just write a normal class, a normal method.What's more, you can just write a interceptor which can executed when the servlet had been invoked.

Comment: the problem is, everytime the PayrollRun is executed, I need to truncate a few tables and then update them with new values, which are received by other servlets and irrelevant to this question.

Comment: sorry, have no idea.But how could you invoke PayrollRun?

Comment: Hmm, well I've decided to use the database suggestion made by ck1 (as a comment to my question). But there's still one problem. I'll try to update the question now.